# Problems tick checkbox using PHPUnit (Functional tests)

Tags: checkbox, phpunit

I have problems to select the checkbox of the following code via PHPUnit.

```
<div id="user_project">
<input type="checkbox" id="user_project_1" name="user[project][]" value="1" checked="checked" />
<label for="user_project_1">Project 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="user_project_2" name="user[project][]" value="2" /><label for="user_project_2">Project 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="user_project_3" name="user[project][]" value="3" checked="checked" />
<label for="user_project_3">Project 3</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="user_project_4" name="user[project][]" value="4" checked="checked" />
<label for="user_project_4">Project 4</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="user_project_5" name="user[project][]" value="5" checked="checked" />
<label for="user_project_5">Project 5</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="user_project_6" name="user[project][]" value="6" checked="checked" />
<label for="user_project_6">Project 6</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="user_project_7" name="user[project][]" value="7" />
<label for="user_project_7">Project 7</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="user_project_10" name="user[project][]" value="10" /><label for="user_project_10">Project 10</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="user_project_12" name="user[project][]" value="12" /><label for="user_project_12">Project 12</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="user_project_13" name="user[project][]" value="13" />
<label for="user_project_13">Project 13</label>
</div>
```

Normally I will tick the checkboxes using "$form["Name of checkbox"]->tick();" - but i cannot change the name (because it is generated via Symfony2).

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you retrieve the form in the `$form` object, try this for select the 2nd element:

```
    $select = $form->get('user[project]');
    $cb = $select[1];  // the second table row
    $cb->tick();
```

Hope this help

Comment: Hi @Atreides78 I update my answer with another code i found in my test case that work for me. Let me know if you have solved.